# Node 'request' method doesn't execute

Tags: node.js, header, request

I have my code trying to execute my `request` method, but it's not going in there. I'm setting up my objects correctly, but what I log doesn't get executed. Am I setting it up incorrectly?

```
req = require("request");

var headers = {
    "Content-Type": "json/application",
    "Authorization": "M6V9Jt2HJa8bcYCjd1xItrVaw1dcHDEY5FRpxdfojhI"
}

var options = {
    url: "'http://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v1/home.json?api-key="+NYTIMESKEY,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers
}

for(var i = 0; i < parsed.results.length; i++){

    abstracts.push(parsed.results[i].abstract);


    var url = formatUrl(abst, "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/data.ashx/amla/text-analytics/v1/GetSentiment?Text=");

            var sentStr = '';
            console.log("in there");
            req(options, function(error, response, body){
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
                    console.log(body);
                    console.log("executing thing");
                }
            });
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all, you have a misprint in your options object.

   > var options = {
   >      url: "'http://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v1/home.json?api key="+NYTIMESKEY,

"url" param has extra single quote. When you try to call req function with current url, you'll get "Type error" (invalid protocol).

2. Secondly, the reason your function doesn't call, could be empty parsed.results array. I've simplified a bit your code. And now req function is called.

```js
req = require("request");

var headers = {
    "Content-Type": "json/application",
    "Authorization": "M6V9Jt2HJa8bcYCjd1xItrVaw1dcHDEY5FRpxdfojhI"
}

var options = {
    url: "http://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v1/home.json?api-key=" + "something_you_nedd",
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers
}

var sentStr = '';
console.log("in there");
req(options, function(error, response, body){
    console.log("on answer");
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        console.log(body);
        console.log("executing thing");
    }
});
```